# Programmatically producing polar or quasi-polar plots with a variable for color in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I would like to create plots using matlab that represent a numerical assessment of quality in a radial fashion.

The best method I've found seems to not work properly.  One runs the following code:

```
theta = (0 : (360/11) : 360)*pi/180;
r = 0 : 2 : 20 ;
[TH,R] = meshgrid(theta,r);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(TH,R);
Z = meshgrid(Data);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

`Data` is a vector of data containing 11 numbers, an example dataset being the following:

```
Data = 0.884, 0.882, 0.879, 0.880, 0.8776, 0.871, 0.8587, 0.829, 0.811, 0.803, 0.780
```

the output of `surf` here is this:

[image: Incorrect surf plot]

I would like to produce a more refined version of this type of image:

[image: mostly correct output]

which I have generated with the following code:

```
for theta = 0 : pi/100 : pi;  
    v = [InterpolatedImageHeight;LengthVector];
    x_center = InterpolatedImageHeight((HorizontalRes+1)/2);
    y_center = 0; %InterpolatedImageHeight((HorizontalRes+1)/2);
    center = repmat([x_center; y_center], 1, length(InterpolatedImageHeight));
    R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
    vo = R*(v - center) + center;
    x_rotated = vo(1,:);
    y_rotated = vo(2,:);
    scatter(x_rotated,y_rotated,DotSize,InterpolatedData,'filled'); %x,y,area,color,properties
end
```

The issue with this is that it is a scatter plot where I am essentially using `plot(r,Data)`, plotting many many copies, and increasing the dot size.  The graphic itself has many seams, this takes an enormous amount of memory, and is time intensive where `surf` or `mesh` will run extremely fast and take minimal memory.

How does one produce concentric rings with a variable input for color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the code by Darren Rowland in [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/276536) I have come up with the following solution:

```
x = interp1(1:length(data),datax,(datax(1):datax(end)/f:datax(end)),'linear'); 
y = interp1(1:length(datay),datay,datay(1):datay(end)/f:datay(end),'spline');
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,n);

xr = x.'*cos(theta);
zr = x.'*sin(theta);
yr = repmat(y.',1,n);

figure;
surf(xy,yr,zr,zr*numcolors);
```

which is elegant, runs quickly, and produces beautiful figures.  This is a sample of the output with some extra chart elements:

[image: sample chart produced by code: Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 Average MTF 30lp/mm map]

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely different plots in your question. The first one represents the data as rays from the origin towards the outside of the circle. The data-points are placed anti-clockwise. A refined version of this can be achieved like this:

```
Data = [0.884, 0.882, 0.879, 0.880, 0.8776, 0.871,...
        0.8587, 0.829, 0.811, 0.803, 0.780]; 

theta = linspace(0,2*pi,length(Data));
r = linspace(0,20,length(Data));
[TH,R] = meshgrid(theta,r);

Z = meshgrid(Data);
[X,Y,Z] = pol2cart(TH,R,Z);

surf(X,Y,Z);
view(2);
shading interp
```

Note that I used `linspace` to generate `theta` and `r` to always match the length of `Data`. `Z` is also passed trough `pol2cart`. Then you can use `shading interp` to remove the lines between the patches and interpolate the color. With `view(2)` you can set the perspective as you would have a 2d-plot.

*This is the result:*

[image: result1]

---

It's relatively easy to get a result like in your second example. There the data-points represent concentric circles around the origin and are placed from the origin towards the outside. Therefore, just transpose the meshgrid of `Z` by using the following line:

```
Z = meshgrid(Data)';
```

*This is the result then:*

[image: result2]